# A bunch of /n's appear when I try to pull text

Tags: python

First try

```
classes = tree.xpath('//*[@data-status="active"]/text()')

print ('Classes: ', classes)
```

Returns this:

```
['Active', '\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n      ', '\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n
  ', '\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n      ', '\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n      ', '\n
', '\n\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n      ', '\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n      ', '\n        ', '\n\n
', '\n\n        ', '\n\n      ', '\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n        ', '\n\n      ']
```

I should be getting all classes with the data status of active, not a bunch of new lines I'm pretty sure.

Or I get an empty array when I extend the xpath to the actual text, which i believe im doing properly
Second Try:

```
classes = tree.xpath('//*[@data-status="active"]/course/title/class-name/text()')
```

Prints out an empty array '[]'

Full Code:

```
from appJar import gui
from splinter import Browser
from lxml import html
import requests
browser = Browser('chrome', headless=True)


browser.visit('www.sitelogin.com')  #Access
browser.fill('username', 'johndoe') #Login
browser.fill('password', 'pass1234') #Login
button = browser.find_by_name('commit') #Login
button.click() #Login

divs = browser.find_by_id("child-89751")
within = divs.first.find_by_name('calculated-grade')
if browser.is_text_present('Current Class Schedule'):
    print("Success")
    print(within)
page = browser.html
tree = html.fromstring(page)
classes = tree.xpath('//*[@data-status="active"]/course/title/class-name/text()')
grades = tree.xpath('//span[@class="numeric-grade"]/text()')

print ('Classes: ', classes)
print ('Grades: ', grades)
```

Expected Output (All active classes on page. Seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNHx1.jpg) The title being the big blue words.:
Expected:

```
Digital Portfolio Grade 9, English 1 H, Algebra 1H etc.
```

Comment: What does your document look like? Without that example this is not very informative.

Comment: You have a print statement which is nothing like what you're saying is returned (a list of strings).

Comment: @tadman It's html downloaded straight from the site
page = browser.html
tree = html.fromstring(page)

Comment: What site? What page? Just...what? You need to be more specific. Think about how we might reproduce your results.

Comment: @PeterWood I guarantee that's what comes out when I run print/

Comment: @tadman Added full code to original post.

Comment: The code is less important than the **data you're processing**. Remember: Garbage in, garbage out. The input data is absolutely critical here. I cannot stress this enough.

Comment: **GIVE**. **US**. **SAMPLE**. **INPUT**. Seriously, this should not be hard. Your description is not helping. I can't feed that text into your program to get the same results you did. If you're having trouble processing data, that's understandable, but we need to know what that data looks like. See [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `sitelogin.com` is a bogus site, we can't tell what you're actually dealing with.

Comment: @tadman Sorry, here we go. This programs job is to login to my school grade book and pull the classes and their respective grades. I'm able to easily pull the grades. The issue is pulling the classes, there are other classes without the data-active attrib. The active attrib indicates that the class is currently taking place aka current semester. There is no grade to pull for nonactive classes but there is class names to pull. I'm trying to only pull the ones that have the 'data-status:active' and I'm only going for the title. 
Pt1

Comment: You need to slow down here, explain less and *show* more. If you can make a minimal HTML document that, if fed into your code there, produces similar results, now we're talking. That picture does not show the HTML structure you're trying to parse. We can't tell if your code is correct, nearly correct, or completely wrong.

Comment: Visual of what im doing: https://imgur.com/FfBUljP
Html: https://gyazo.com/bcd1e8651c05581ed45ea59faf2cf352
I can't give the real site/login due to it being essentially a company login, it's not a public login site.

Comment: @tadman This is the HTML I'm processing, slightly tampered to remove login info, https://gist.github.com/sapblatt11/d65be974ef9dcfb41a91679dbeb97de2 opening that without internet would yield the current page I'm processing. Upon running 'tree.xpath('//*[@data-status="active"]/text()')' it returns all the \n's.

Comment: That's better, but a smaller, minimal example of that you can include in your code would be best. At least we can see what you're trying to process now.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` are part of the string you are passing to `html.fromstring(page)`

You can omit them by running:

```
page = ' '.join(page.split('\n'))
html.fromstring(page)
```

Comment: Yes that should work, but there is something wrong with text, as it is only blankspace between the \n's not any text.

Comment: Please update your question with an output of what you expect to see.

Comment: Added the expected.

Comment: Wed need the page source to see if the code is working. I.e. we need to see what the code sees. In chrome do: view-source:<URL HERE>

Comment: slightly tampered to remove login info, gist.github.com/sapblatt11/d65be974ef9dcfb41a91679dbeb97de2 opening that without internet would yield the current page I'm processing.